# Is it safe to run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`

Tags: powershell

I installed this module from https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0 inside our windows power shell:-

```
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -RequiredVersion 7.1.0
```

Then i run this command, but i got that the script is not digitally signed:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Import-Module ImportExcel
Import-Module : File C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ImportExcel\7.1.0\ImportExcel.psm1 cannot be loaded.
The file C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ImportExcel\7.1.0\ImportExcel.psm1 is not digitally signed. You
cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy,
see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module ImportExcel
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [Import-Module], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

and to fix this i run this command `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`.. so is this safe?

Comment: "PowerShell's execution policy is a safety feature that controls the conditions under which PowerShell loads configuration files and runs scripts. This feature helps prevent the execution of malicious scripts." - PowerShell Gallery is a trusted repository, the execution policy is there to let you know that executing scripts downloaded from untrusted repositories __can__ be dangerous.

Comment: Santiago Sqarzon's comment is correct. It's important to understand that PowerShell execution policy is a safety feature that admins can use to prevent accidental execution of unsigned code, but it is not a security boundary. (The security boundary is the account running the code, not PowerShell or code that PowerShell executes.)

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr**

```
# Save the current execution policy...
$currPolicy = Get-ExecutionPolicy
# ... and temporarily set the policy to 'Bypass' for this process.
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force

# ASSUMING YOU TRUST MODULE ImportExcel:
# Execution of scripts in the context of importing the module is
# now permitted.
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -RequiredVersion 7.1.0 

# Restore the previous execution policy for this process.
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy $currPolicy -Force
```

---

To paraphrase [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)'s helpful comment on the question:

PowerShell's [execution policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) prevent *potential* harm by controlling if and under what conditions the execution of *script* files (`.ps1`) is permitted: `Restricted` prevents execution altogether, `AllSigned` only allows cryptographically *signed* scripts to execute, `RemoteSigned` requires only scripts *downloaded from the web* to be signed, `Unrestricted` places no restriction on execution but *prompts* to confirm the intent to execute internet-downloaded scripts, `Bypass` doesn't restrict execution at all.

This means when the effective policy prevents execution of a given script, the implication is *not* that the particular script *actually* contains harmful content - the policies never check for that, they purely act on formal criteria.

Conversely, of course, any given script *could* contain harmful content.

It looks like you're using the [`ImportExcel` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel) from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com), the official repository for open-source PowerShell modules; the gallery subjects modules submitted to it to [security checks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-gallery-new-security-scan/).

The fact that you've already *installed* this module suggests that you *trust* it in principle. (Of course, you can inspect the script in question - and the module as a whole - yourself, via the directory that `(Get-Module ImportExcel -ListAvailable).Path` reports.)

Importing it just so *happens to* involve running a *script* (`*.ps1`), which not all [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules) do (doing so is used for module-internal helper scripts or for required modifications to the *caller*'s scope via the script specified in the `ScriptsToProcess`  [module-manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest) entry).

To put it differently:

- An `Import-Module` call may not involve execution of *scripts* at all, yet it invariably involves *importing commands* into your session, which you should definitely *trust* in order to use them.
- Importing a module should therefore be an all-or-nothing trust proposition, and if you *do* trust it, the effective execution policy should not get in the way of importing it.

The code shown above minimizes the risk of making the process-level policy more permissive by effectively scoping it to the module import of interest.

---

As an aside: The problem wouldn't even arise on *Unix-like platforms* (which requires the cross-platform [PowerShell (Core) v6+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition), where execution policies do not apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this command in your terminal.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser
```

This should then ask for a value at which point you can set it to Bypass / RemoteSigned